Configurar firma en flutter para subir a google play u
en la version giraffe de android studio con flutter configuraba las llaves de la firma en el archivo android/app/build.gradle le configuraba asi
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

pero actualice la ultima version de flutter y de android stuido que es koala pero al estructura de los archivos gradle cambio y ya no me acepta poner este codigo en la el archivo inicado.
me podirana ayudar ahora donde se configrua los keys de la firma para su despliegue en google play .
